# Latent Dirichlet Allocation on Sparse Matrix (

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, topic-modeling

I'm trying to run topic modeling using lda 1.0.2 package on Python.

My input is a sparse matrix of class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'.

It currently seems like this doesn't work, and raises the following error:

> > > lda_class.fit(data)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\gw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lda\lda.py", line 120, in fit
> > >           self._fit(X)
> > >         File "C:\Users\gw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lda\lda.py", line 214, in _fit
> > >           self._initialize(X)
> > >         File "C:\Users\gw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lda\lda.py", line 257, in _initialize
> > >           w, d = WS[i], DS[i]
> > >       IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and how to approach it?

Comment: What is the format of the dataset ?

Comment: As i wrote in the question, the format is csr:   >>> type(data)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>